# Find indexes of two Elements in array whose sum is equal or nearly equal to K given as Input

Tags: java

We have to print the indexes of two elements in the array whose sum is either equal or nearly equal to the number K given as Input. 
Array can have positive or negative integers. 
The complexity should be less then O(n*n).

Comment: Guessing you're here just seeking a solution rather than attempting anything yourself?  Please post some code or even pseudo code of what you have tried and we can help correct / improve your solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question, but it does not include the required summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.